# Renaming File in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename a file so I can remove the brackets within the name:

Example: `[Example] Test File (Servers).xls` renamed to `Example Test File (Servers).xls`

My issue is that when I run this, it returns an error saying

```
Rename-Item -Path '.\'[Example'] Test File (Servers).xls' -NewName "Example Test File (Servers).xls"
```

> Rename-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Users\Documents\PowerShell\[Example] Test File (Servers).xls does not exist

The other issue is that when I run:

```
C:\Users\Documents\PowerShell> Get-ChildItem -Path "[Example] Test File (Servers).xls"
```

This runs successfully with no errors, so I know PowerShell is finding this file with no problems. At this point, I don't know why this isn't working because it can find the file with one command, and not with the other.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21008180/847990 You have to use double back-ticks in order to escape those brackets in the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LiteralPath` instead of `Path` if you're using a modern version of Powershell (v4+ iirc).

It can deal with special characters like `[]` without having to escape them.

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath ".\[Example] Test File (Servers).xls" -NewName "Example Test File (Servers).xls"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

For changing multiple-filenames in the same directory:

`Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "[Example]","Example"}`

Filename before:

> [Example] Test File (Servers).xls

Filename after:

> Example Test File (Servers).xls

Comment: Is there an explicit reason why you use the alias instead of the normal `Get-Childitem`?

Comment: @Paxz get-childitem is just an alias for dir. see documentation.

Comment: The documentation states the opposite (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @Paxz potato potato, get-childitem is an alias for dir. And vise versa. They both do the same is what i meant.  Dir is just the abbreviated version. Eg. `get-ChildItem - recursive` == `Dir -r`