# Translation from Powershell to Python

Tags: python, powershell

I'm working on a simple script I have used to work/edit a large folder with movies/tv-shows and I have found an easy way to remove certain strings in folder and file titles, but it is a PowerShell command and I have the rest of my functions in a Python script.

1. First, I'm asking for someone who might be able to make a Python equivalent to this PowerShell line:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'SomeString'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'SomeString', ''}
   ```
2. Second, I have experienced issues with the PowerShell command if the string I want removed contains the `[]` (like this: `-[Something]`) - the titles will become unreadable and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy file with square brackets \[ \] in the filename and use \* wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008180/copy-file-with-square-brackets-in-the-filename-and-use-wildcard)

Comment: I have not yet tried to translate the PowerShell script into Python because I am not very skilled in either...

Comment: Thanks  anonjnr, the double-backtick approach works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the double-backtick approach could work, I'd recommend [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. Safe and useful if a string to be escaped comes from an external source.

**[`Regex.Escape(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

> *Escapes a **minimal set of characters*** (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`,`)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#`, and *white space*) by replacing
>   them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression
>   engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as
>   metacharacters.

**Example**:

```
$SomeString = '[square]'
$SafeString = [regex]::Escape( $SomeString )
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match $SafeString } | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ | 
        Rename-Item -NewName $($_.Name -replace $SafeString, '')  -WhatIf
    }
```

**Result**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\53619911.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\PShell\DataFi
les\some[square]file.txt Destination: D:\PShell\DataFiles\somefile.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\PShell\DataFi
les\some[square]file2.txt Destination: D:\PShell\DataFiles\somefile2.txt".
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problems and works for me. Thanks to JosefZ who showed how Regex.Escape method was used.

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder'
CD $dir
$SomeString = '-[String.String]'
$SafeString = [regex]::Escape( $SomeString )
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $SafeString} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $SafeString, ''}
```

This will remove all -[String.String] from any folder and file title in the path.