# Powershell Get-Content failing spuriously

Tags: powershell

I have a fairly simple PS script that was working perfectly, and now has suddenly started giving errors. I have narrowed the problem portion to a couple of Get-Content statements. Here's what the affected part of the script looks like:

```
$pathSource = "D:\FileDirectory"
Set-Location -Path $pathSource
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path FilesA*.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII FilesA_Digest.txt
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path FilesB*.txt | Out-File -Encoding ASCII FilesB_Digest.txt
```

This part of the script gathers up a collection of like-named files and concatenates them into a single text file for uploading to an FTP site. The Get-Content/Out-File was needed as the original files are encoded incorrectly for the FTP site. The script was working perfectly, running once each night for several weeks. Now, it gets the following error when the Get-Content statements are reached:

```
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.
At D:\FileDirectory\Script.ps1
```

Environment is Windows Server 2016. I've tried different variations on the Get-Content parameters, but nothing has worked. I know there is a bug that affects network-mapped drives, but that's not the case here -- all files are local.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: `-Path FilesA*.txt` would include the Out-File `FilesA_Digest.txt` on successive runs.

Comment: As an aside: applying `-Encoding ASCII` to (originally) UTF-8-encoded data may result in _loss of information_: any characters in the input that are outside the ASCII range will be transliterated to _literal_ `?` characters. (By contrast, If the original data contains _only_ ASCII-range characters, there's no need to transcode at all, given that UTF-8 is a _superset_ of ASCII.)

Comment: @LotPings -- that was a typo on my part, since I was using dummy filenames that don't actually match the original script. The original script doesn't suffer from that issue.

Comment: @mklelement0 -- I realize that there may be a data loss issue, but the reality is that there won't be, since the source file doesn't contain any characters outside the standard ASCII set.

Comment: @npowroz: I see, but that contradicts your claim "the original files are encoded incorrectly": If you can read them correctly with `-Encoding UTF8` _and_ they only contain ASCII-range characters, you don't need any transcoding at all.

Comment: @mklelement0: I was skipping over details that didn't matter. The reality is that the files were being created by Powershell encoded as "UCS-2 LE BOM". The receiving application at the end of the FTP connection bombs when it sees that, so by adding the -Encoding parameters the encoding problem gets fixed.

Comment: @npowroz: If your files have a BOM, then what you pass to `-Encoding` when you call `Get-Content` is irrelevant, and passing `UTF8`, which doesn't match the _actual_ encoding, is confusing. (It sounds like the actual encoding is UTF-16LE (which PowerShell misleadingly calls `Unicode`), which is what I presume you meant by "UCS2 LE", which, strictly speaking is _not_ the same as UTF-16LE. UTF-16LE (with BOM) is what Windows PowerShell produces by default with `>` and `Out-File` (but _not_ with `Set-Content`)).

Comment: Restarting PowerShell fixed it for me... weird though.

Answer (score 1):

The only plausible explanation I can think of is that **a *custom* `Get-Content` command that lacks an `-Encoding` parameter is *shadowing* (overriding) the standard `Get-Content` cmdlet** in the PowerShell session that's executing your script.

To demonstrate:

```
# Define a custom Get-Content command (function) that accepts only 
# a (positional) -Path parameter, not also -Encoding.
function Get-Content { [CmdletBinding()] param([string] $Path) }

# Now try to use Get-Content -Encoding
Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 FilesA*.txt
```

You'll see the same error message as in your question.

**Use `Get-Command Get-Content -All` to see all commands named `Get-Content`**, with the *effective* command listed first.

Then examine where any custom commands may come from; e.g., your `$PROFILE` script may contain one.

To **rule out `$PROFILE` as the culprit**, start PowerShell without loading the profile script and examine `Get-Content` then:

```
powershell -noprofile  # Windows PowerShell
pwsh -noprofile        # PowerShell Core
```

A **simple way to rule out custom overrides *ad hoc*** is to **call a command by its *module-qualified name***:

```
Microsoft.Powershell.Management\Get-Content ...
```

You can determine a built-in cmdlet's module name of origin as follows:

```
PS> (Get-Command Get-Content -All)[-1].ModuleName
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

In a pinch you can also ***infer* the originating module name from the *URL of the help topic***:

- Googling `Get-Content` will take you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content - note how the cmdlet's module name, `microsoft.powershell.management` (case doesn't matter), is the penultimate (next to last) URI component.

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions and still get the same error, so now I'm really at a loss. I know I'm using the built-in Get-Content with no overrides, no customization, nothing special. This is truly weird.

Comment: @npowroz: So if you run your `*.ps1` script from a PowerShell instance that you've started with `-noprofile` and that reports `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` for `(Get-Command Get-Content).ModuleName` you still get the same error?

Comment: @npowroz: If you do `Format-Hex <your-script>`, does it look like any invisible control characters are present in your file?

Comment: Doing "Get-Command Get-Content" returns "Version 3.1.0.0 / Source Microsoft.PowerShell.Management" after I started it with -noprofile. I've dumped it using Format-Hex, but I'm not seeing anything that sticks out at me.

Comment: @npowroz: See if the issue is specific to a given machine with a given PowerShell / OS version.

Comment: I just tested it on a Windows Server 2008 instance, running whatever version of PowerShell comes with that (1.0 I think). Same error -- (to paraphrase) "Parameter -Encoding is invalid". The only thing that comes to mind is that some patch has broken things, but I have no idea if I'm even in the right universe.

Comment: @npowroz: What is the _exact_ error message? Is it different from the one you cite in your question?

Comment: Nope, it's exactly the same as the one I cited in the original question. That's the reason why I paraphrased. Apologies if that created a red herring. And I know that it's not a profile issue on that machine as I have never run PowerShell on it. As well, the call to Get-Content was the long form "Microsoft.Powershell.Management\Get-Content -Encoding ..."

Comment: @mklelement0: It just got weirder. I tested the Get-Content on a different server, another implementation of Server 2016. It worked perfectly, with no errors. Interestingly, that machine is a little out of date with its patches. I'm leaning more and more toward a bad patch that is breaking the Get-Content applet in Powershell.

Comment: @npowroz: W2K8 indeed _originally_ came with PSv1, _which no one should be using anymore_ - you can't even find documentation for it anymore, so I can't tell if v1's `Get-Content` had an `-Encoding` parameter. Even if it didn't, it wouldn't explain how your _previously working_ script stopped working - unless you ran it on a _different_ machine. `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` will tell you what version a given machine is running.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with the out command. Can you please try below code :

```
$pathSource = "D:\FileDirectory"
Set-Location -Path $pathSource
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path FilesA*.txt | Set-Content  -Encoding ASCII -path FilesA_Digest.txt
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path FilesB*.txt | Set-Content  -Encoding ASCII -path FilesB_Digest.txt
```

Comment: `Out-File` is _not_ the problem, given that the OP's error message clearly mentions `Get-Content` as the offending cmdlet: `Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why it failed, but I can say that I have completely re-written the script and now it works. I have to note that, given the errors that were occurring, I also don't know why it is now working.

I am using the exact same calls to the Get-Content commandlet, with the -Encoding parameter and the pipe to Out-File with its own -Encoding parameter. I am doing the exact same actions as the previous version of the script. The only part that is significantly different is the portion that performs the FTP transfer of the processed files. I'm now using only PowerShell to perform the transfer rather than CuteFTP and it all seems to be working correctly.

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Cheers
Norm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I was running into the same with:

```
$n = ni '[hi]' -value 'some text'
gc $n -Encoding Byte
$f = ls *hi*
$f.where{$_.name -eq '[hi]'}.Delete()
```

also looks like there's already a chain of SOs about this known bug [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778204/4496560)