# Powershell color formatting with format operator

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

I'm using a format operator inside a script with a following example:

```
$current = 1
$total   = 1250
$userCN  = "contoso.com/CONTOSO/Users/Adam Smith"

"{0, -35}: {1}" -f "SUCCESS: Updated user $current/$total", $userCN
```

This excpectedly shows the following output:

`SUCCESS: Updated user 1/1250       : contoso.com/CONTOSO/Users/Adam Smith`

The format operator is there to keep the targeted output text in place with current / total running numbers varying between 1-99999. Without the format operator I could highlight the success line like this:

`Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "SUCCESS: Updated user $current/$total: $userCN"`

But the question is how could I use the highlight-colors combined with the format operator? There's only the `-f` parameter and it doesn't allow the color parameters because, well, it's not the same thing as `Write-Host` in the first place.

Comment: Apply the [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#subexpression-operator--)

Comment: Put the formatting stuff between brackets and Write-Host that like `Write-Host ("{0, -35}: {1}" -f "SUCCESS: Updated user $current/$total", $userCN) -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green`

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! The documentation above defines subexpressions to be used with dollar sign as well but it works with or without it. I guess I'll go with the specification and put the $ in place.

Comment: @JosefZ: I suggest not recommending `$(...)` for passing _command arguments_ - `(...)` is sufficient in the vast majority of cases and doesn't have side effects; use `$(...)` / `@(...)` only if you need to embed _compound statements_ or _multiple_ commands or expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike other shells, PowerShell allows you to **pass commands and expressions as *command arguments*** simply by **enclosing them in *parentheses*, i.e by using `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)**.

When calling *PowerShell* commands (cmdlets, scripts, functions), the output is passed as-is as an argument, as its original output type.

Therefore, [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s solution from a comment is correct:

```bash
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green `
           ("{0, -35}: {1}" -f "SUCCESS: Updated user $current/$total", $userCN)
```

That is, the `-f` expression inside `(...)` is executed and its output - a single string in this case - is passed as a positional argument to `Write-Host` (implicitly binds to the `-Object` parameter).

---

Note that **you do *not* need, `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#subexpression-operator--), in this case:**

**`(...)` is sufficient to enclose an expression or command.**

- **Note**: You don't even need `(...)` in order to pass the value of a single variable (e.g., `$var`) - even if it contains spaces - or to pass the value of one of its *properties* (e.g, `$var.SomeProp`), or even the return value from a call to one of its *methods* (e.g., `$var.SomeMethod()`).

In fact, in certain cases **`$(...)` can inadvertently *modify* your argument**, because it acts like the pipeline; that is, it *enumerates and rebuilds array expressions* as regular PowerShell arrays (potentially losing strong typing) and *unwraps single-element arrays*:

```bash
# Pass a single-element array to a script block (which acts like a function).
# (...) preserves the array as-is.
PS> & { param($array) $array.GetType().Name } -array ([array] 1)
Object[]  # OK - single-element array was passed as-is

# $(...) unwraps it.
PS> & { param($array) $array.GetType().Name } -array $([array] 1)
Int32  # !! Single-element array was unwrapped.

# Strongly-typed array example:
PS> & { param($array) $array.GetType().Name } ([int[]] (1..10))
Int32[] # OK - strongly typed array was passed as-is.

# Strongly-typed array example:
PS> & { param($array) $array.GetType().Name } $([int[]] (1..10))
Object[] # !! Array was *enumerated and *rebuilt* as regular PowerShell array.
```

The **primary use of `$(...)`** is:

- expanding the output from expressions or commands  **inside [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031158/45375)** (string interpolation)
- To send the **output from *compound statements*** such as `foreach (...) { ... }` and `if (...) { ... }` or ***multiple* statements** directly through the pipeline, after *collecting the output up front* (which `(...)` does as well); however, you can alternatively wrap such statements `& { ... }` (or `. { ... }` in order to execute directly in the caller's scope rather than a child scope) in order to get the usual *streaming* behavior (one-by-one passing of output) in the pipeline.

  - Taking a step back: Given that you already *can* use compound statements as *expressions* in variable assignments - e.g., `$evenNums = foreach ($num in 1..3) { $num * 2 }` - and expressions *generally* are accepted as the first segment of a pipeline - e.g., `'hi' | Write-Host -Fore Yellow` - it is surprising that that currently doesn't work with compound statements; [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817) asks if this limitation can be lifted.

**In the context of passing *arguments* to *commands*:**

- **Use `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#subexpression-operator--) *only if*** you want to pass the output from *multiple* commands or (one or more) *compound statements* as an argument *and/or*, if the output happens to be a *single* object, you want that object to be used as-is or, if it happens to be a single-element array (enumerable), you want it to be *unwrapped* (pass the element itself, not the array.

  - Of course, if you're constructing a *string* argument, `$(...)` can be useful *inside that string*, for string interpolation - e.g., `Write-Host "1 + 1 = $(1 + 1)"`
- **Use `@(...)`, the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#array-subexpression-operator--) *only if*** you want to pass the output from *multiple* commands as an argument *and/or* you want to *ensure* that the output becomes a *array*; that is, the output is returned as a (regular PowerShell) array, of type `[object[]]`, even if it happens to comprise just *one* object. In a manner of speaking it is the *inverse* of `$(...)`'s behavior in the single-object output case: it ensures that single-object output too becomes an array.