# Is it possible to pipe the result of a while loop without assigning to a variable

Tags: powershell

The following code doesn't work

```
$result = (
    while ($true) { 
        <# Generating long list of psobject #> 
    }) | Tee-Object -FilePath 'fname.csv' | Group-Object -Property xxx | Select Name,Count
```

> The term 'while' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: i cannot think of any reason why it SHOULD work in that situation. what are you actually attempting to achieve?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Yes, [it should work](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817).

Comment: @mklement0 - thank you for the info [*grin*] ... i disagree that it should work _in that situation_, but i can see that you - and others - would view it differently. i have enjoyed reading the workaround in your answer.

Comment: i see the use of an expression around the `while` to be ... a bizarre, forced weirdness. it aint at all obvious and will be problematic when it comes to long term maintenance. that is not what the structure seems to be designed for. the more appropriate way would be to determine WHY the OP chose such an awkward structure - and then see if there are more obvious - and therefore more maintainable - solutions.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: The idea is not to use an expression _around_ the `while` loop, the idea is to be able to use the `while` loop _itself_ as an expression, _consistently_; you can already do it in a (non-pipeline) assignment, but you can't in a pipeline - there is no reason for this inconsistency, and it is the currently required workaround that is awkward and obscure. As for the _why_ : it should be possible to send _any_ expression's or statement's output to the pipeline, without having to jump through hoops. Pipeline input doesn't always have to come from _cmdlets_.

Comment: `$result = $(`  will fix the parsing error, although an assignment normally has no output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While:

- **you can use *expressions* as the first segment of a *pipeline*** (e.g., 
  `1..2 | Tee-Object -Variable result`),
- **you *cannot* use *compound statements*** (aka ***language statements***) such as `if`, `while`, `foreach`, and `do` as-is, unfortunately.

That is, such **compound statements aren't true expressions**, even though in the context of *assignments* they can act a such. That is, you could do `$result = while ($true) ...` - without enclosing the `while`  in `(...)` - yet you cannot send the `while` loop directly *through a pipeline*.

See [GitHub issue #6817](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817), which discusses this problematic "half-expression status" of compound statements, and asks if it's feasible to make them full expressions; [as it turns out](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967#issuecomment-561843650), the fundamentals of PowerShell's grammar prevent that.

**Workarounds**:

- **If you want your looping compound statement to *stream*, i.e. to output its objects *one by one* to the pipeline**, as they become available - i.e. if you want the **standard, *streaming* pipeline behavior**:

  - **Wrap your compound statement in `& { ... }`** (or `. { ... }`, if you want to run directly in the current rather than in a child scope).
  - E.g., `& { foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i } } | Tee-Object -Variable result`
- If you want to **collect all outputs from your looping compound statement *up front***, *before* sending them through the pipeline:

  - **Wrap your compound statement in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**.
  - E.g., `$(foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i }) | Tee-Object -Variable result`
  - Note:

    - While using `$(...)` over `& { ... }` can speed up your pipeline, it does so only slightly, and it **potentially comes at the expense of memory consumption**, given that all outputs are *invariably* collected in memory first.
    - The same applies to `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) and `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), but note that `(...)` only works with a single *expression* or *command*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375) contrasts `(...)`, `$(...)` and `@(...)` in detail.

---

Applied to your case:

```bash
$result = & {
    while ($true) { 
        <# Generating long list of psobject #> 
    } 
  } | Tee-Object -FilePath 'fname.csv' | ...
```