# Powershell navigate to specific directory

Tags: powershell

Total powershell noob and trying to go into a directory. I know it is the last directory (alphabetically) and I can get that with

`Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1`

I then want to `Set-Location` to that but I can't figure out how to call it with the output of the above.

I was trying something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1

Set-Variable -Name "Dir" -Value { Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1 }

Set-Location -Path $Dir
```

but that doesn't work at all. Any pointers?

Comment: What's wrong with using the pipe?  `Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1 | Set-Location`  or better  `Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1 | Push-Location `

Comment: I agree with @Olaf on using the pipeline but I just figured I'd mention that `Set-Variable -Name "Dir" -Value $(Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1)` would work in your example. The way you have it you're actually saving the actual scriptblock to the variable rather than the result of running `Get-ChildItem`. Just for reference, the ScriptBlock can be invoked and used `Set-Location -Path $($Dir.Invoke())` but again, go with the pipeline solution Olaf mentioned.

Comment: Fantastic thanks very much that's what I need. I have never used PS before, I wasn't sure what a pipe did... I'm still not 100% sure! I will have a read.

Comment: @notjustme that is really helpful thanks - explains all the things I was missing in my attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>There's good information in the comments, let me try to summarize and complement them:</sup>

- `{ ... }` is a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literal in PowerShell: a reusable piece of code to be invoked *later* with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); that is, what's inside the curly braces is *not* executed right away.
- Given that you want the *execute and return the output from* a command as the argument to another command, use `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
Set-Variable -Name Dir -Value (Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1)
```

However, there is rarely a need to use the [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlet, given that simple assignments - `$Dir = ...` work too, in which case you don't even need the parentheses:

```
$Dir = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Of course, just like you can pass an `(...)` expression to `Set-Variable`, you can pass it to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) directly, in which case you don't need an intermediate variable at all (parameter `-Path` is positionally implied):

```
Set-Location (Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1)
```

You can make this more concise by directly *indexing* the `Get-ChildItem` call's output<sup>[2]</sup>; `[-1]` refers to the *last* array element (output object):

```
Set-Location (Get-ChildItem -Directory)[-1]
```

The alternative is to use the pipeline (see [`about_Pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)):

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1 | Set-Location
```

Note that there are subtle differences between the last 3 commands in the event that *no* subdirectories exist in the current directory (meaning that `Get-ChildItem -Directory` produces no output):

- `Set-Location (Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1)` will report an *error*, because you're then effectively passing `$null` as the `-Path` argument.
- `Set-Location (Get-ChildItem -Directory)[-1]` will also report an error, because you cannot apply an index to a `$null` value.
- `Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -Last 1 | Set-Location`, by contrast, will be a *no-op*, because `Set-Location` effectively won't be invoked at all, due to not receiving input via the pipeline.

If not having subdirectories is an unexpected condition, you can force the script to abort by adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to one of the first two commands - see [`about_CommonParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters).

---

<sup>[1] While `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), works too, it's usually not necessary - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that doing so means that all output from the `Get-ChildItem` call is then collected in memory first, but that is unlikely to be a problem in this case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489712/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: Really helpful and the extra explanation it hugely appreciated, thanks very much

Comment: Glad to hear it, @DominicShaw; my pleasure. Please also see the footnote that I've just added re streaming behavior in the pipeline vs. up-front collection of all outputs via `(...)`

Comment: Good summarization and explaination. That footnote reference alone is an instant +1 considering the topic. :)