# Where is program's path for PowerShell command?

Tags: windows, git, powershell

Command 'git' is available from PowerShell, I want to know where is git installed on my PC, so I tried to execute such 'script'

```
PS> where git
```

but after execution I see nothing, only prompt for new command.
Question: How can I find path for command in Windows 10?

Comment: `$(get-command git).Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell, `where` is an alias for [`where-object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7), which is used to filter collections.

```
Get-Alias -Name where                                                                
CommandType     Name                          Version    Source
-----------     ----                          -------    ------
Alias           where -> Where-Object
```

In Cmd, [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where_1) displays location of files.

The Powershell version of Cmd's `where` is [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7)

```
Get-Command -Name git
CommandType     Name                        Version    Source
-----------     ----                        -------    ------
Application     git.exe                     2.20.1.1   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: Helpful, but note that `where.exe` - an external executable - has nothing to do with `cmd`, and that you can invoke it from PowerShell simply by including the filename extension: `where.exe git`.

Answer (score 17):

<sup>The existing answers are helpful, but I think a more systematic discussion is helpful too.</sup>

**tl;dr**

`where` is PowerShell's built-in *alias* for the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet; to invoke the external `where.exe` *program*, use `.exe` explicitly:<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
# Note the use of '.exe' to disambiguate the external 'where.exe' program
# from PowerShell's built-in 'where' alias (for 'Where-Object').
PS> where.exe git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

**`where.exe`**, whose purpose is return the full path of an executable in the system's path (in one of the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable), is ***unrelated* to `cmd`** (the legacy command processor): it is an *external executable* that comes with Windows, and it can be invoked from *any* shell, and therefore also from PowerShell.
By contrast, `cmd` does have so-called *internal* commands that indeed can only be called from `cmd`, such as `mklink`; in fact, in `cmd` you can use `where <name>` to infer whether a given (functioning) command `<name>` is internal or not: if there's *no output*, the command is *internal* (or doesn't exist at all).

**Alternatively**, use the **equivalent and more flexible PowerShell counterpart to `where.exe`, the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet**; it returns [`System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinfo) instances (or instances of derived classes), whose `.Source` property contains the full path for a command-info object representing an external executable:

```
PS> (Get-Command git).Source
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Note:

- `where.exe` finds only *executable files*, whereas `Get-Command` by default looks for *all* command types (aliases, functions, cmdlets, ...) - see next section.
- Unlike `Get-Command`, `where.exe` also finds executables located in the *current* directory. `Get-Command` doesn't do that, because PowerShell by design, for security reasons, doesn't allow calling executables located in the current directory by *name only* - a *path* is required (e.g., `.\foo`).

---

**PowerShell has different *types* of commands, which - in the case of name conflicts - have a predefined order of precedence to determine what type should be the effective command.**

That is, if a given command name matches two or more commands, it is their type that determines which command is actually invoked.

This precedence is documented in the conceptual [`about_Command_Precedence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence) help topic; in short, here is the **command precedence by type** in descending order (highest precedence first):

- aliases
- function
- cmdlets (loosely speaking: functions implemented as compiled binaries)
- external executables, including `*.ps1` script files - see bottom section

An easy way **to see what command types exist for a given name is to add the `-All` switch when calling the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet**, which lists the matching commands in descending order of precedence; that is, **the command that will actually be executed via the given name is listed *first***.

```
PS> Get-Command -All where

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           where -> Where-Object
Application     where.exe                                          10.0.18... C:\WINDOWS\system32\where.exe
```

The result shows that the built-in `where` alias for the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet (whose purpose is to filter pipeline input) is the effective command when you submit `where`, and *not* the desired `where.exe` executable.

**Given that the `where.exe` executable file name has the `.exe` extension that can distinguish it from the `where` alias, it is simplest to invoke `where.exe` *with the filename extension***, as shown at the top.

In cases where this is *not* possible (e.g., on Unix-like platforms, where executables typically do not have a filename extension or if an alias shadows a function), **you can use the `-Type` parameter to get the command of interest, and invoke it with `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```
# Invokes where.exe, as only it is of type 'Application' (external executable)
& (Get-Command -Type Application where) git
```

<sup>Should there be *multiple* external executables whose base file name is `where`, it is the one from the directory listed *earliest* in `$env:PATH` that will be executed - see next section.</sup>

---

#### Precedence among external executables and `*.ps1` scripts:

Note:

- One important difference between `cmd` and PowerShell is that PowerShell - by design, for security reasons - does *not* allow you to invoke an external executable or `.ps1` script located in the *current* directory by *name* only; to do so, you must use a *path*, in the simplest case by prepending `.\` (or `./`); e.g., to invoke an executable `foo` located in the current directory, you must use `./foo ...`
- The precedence between `*.ps1` scripts and other executables in effect differs by platform (Windows vs. Unix-like platforms), as detailed below.
- The following discussion assumes that a given command name isn't shadowed by higher-precedence command types, such as aliases, and resolves to an external executable or `*.ps1` script.

Precedence rules:

- When a command name resolves to potentially *multiple* external executables or `*.ps1` scripts via the directories listed in the **`$env:PATH`** environment variable, **the executable / script located in the directory that is listed *earliest* is invoked**.
- If, in that earliest directory:

  - the **given name *exactly* matches an executable file name** (e.g., `where.exe`) or script (e.g., `foo.ps1`), there is **no ambiguity**, and that executable / script is invoked.
  - **the given name *doesn't include a filename extension* (e.g., `foo`), *multiple* executables can match** (via *implied* filename extensions), and the one to actually invoke is determined as follows:

    - On **Windows**:

      - **PowerShell gives precedence to its own scripts**, so **if a `.ps1` script is present, it is the effective command**; note that `.ps1` scripts are executed *in-process*, unlike external executables, which invariably run in a *child process*.
      - Otherwise, it is **the executable file whose filename extension is listed *earliest* among the executable extensions in the `$env:PATHEXT` environment variable**; e.g., `foo.bat` takes precedence over `foo.vbs`, because, `.BAT` is listed before `.VBS`.
    - On **Unix-like platforms** (Linux, macOS):

      - Unix-like platforms determine executability solely via [*permissions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)), not via filename extensions, and executables in the vast majority of cases have *no* filename extension (e.g., just `git`, not `git.exe` as on Windows).
      - From PowerShell's perspective, the only filename extension that matters with respect to executability on Unix is `.ps1`, because it is *PowerShell itself* that considers such files executable - irrespective of whether they are from the *system*'s perspective.
      - Therefore, **in PowerShell on Unix, `.ps1` is the *only* implied filename extension that can be omitted on invocation**; e.g., you can invoke a script file `foo.ps1` as just `foo` (assuming it is in the system's path).
      - If you have an external executable whose file name doesn't have a filename extension - as is typical - and a `.ps1` file with the same base name in the same directory, it is the *external executable* that takes precedence - the reason is that the extension-less name is an *exact* match for the extension-less executable file name.

        - E.g., **if external executable `foo` and `foo.ps1` are located in the same (earliest) directory, submitting `foo` invokes the *external executable*, not `foo.ps1` - unlike on Windows.**

Note:

- The precedence rules among multiple executables in a given directory also apply when using an *explicit path* (without a filename extension); e.g., invoking `./foo` decides the precedence among multiple executables in the current directory whose *base* name is `foo` as described above.
- Placing `.ps1` scripts in a directory listed in `$env:PATH` and invoking them by (base) name only isn't all that common, although it is worth considering as an alternative to putting potentially many *functions* in one's `$PROFILE` file.

  - Unfortunately, the UX is poor on *Linux*, where, due to its case-*sensitive* file system, you must specify the (base) file name *case-exactly* on invocation, whereas PowerShell command invocation is otherwise case-*insensitive*; e.g., if the actual file name is `Get-Foo.ps1`, only `Get-Foo` works for invocation, not `get-foo`.

---

<sup>[1] As for why a call such as `where git` - i.e. mistaken use of `Where-Object` - doesn't produce output: The call is equivalent to `Where-Object git`, which is in turn equivalent to `Where-Object { $_.git }`, which, in the absence of *pipeline input* to the cmdlet by definition never produces output.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$(get-command <command name>).path
```

or

```
$(get-command <command name>).source
```

or in your case

```
$(get-command git).path
```

or

```
$(get-command git).source
```

`get-command` gets cmdlet info and there is a `source` parameter so if you use `get-command` as a variable, you can access the path of the cmdlet.

You can also use the cmd version in powershell with

```
cmd /c "where git"
```

Comment: Helpful, but note that there's no reason to use `$(...)`, which is unnecessary and can have side effects - just use `(...)` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375. Also, `where.exe git` will do; the external `where.exe` executable has nothing to do with `cmd`.