# Why are (return) and return different?

Tags: powershell

I was testing a function and was playing around with what I could do with `return` and stumbled accross a strange issue, in PowerShell 5.1 and PwSh 7.1, the `return` cmdlet seemd to not work in a group:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> return "test"
test
PS C:\Users\Neko> (return "test")
return : The term 'return' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ (return "test")
+  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (return:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I put `return` in a group, it seemed to become unrecognized by PowerShell.

I understand that return prints to the console and does not have "output" per say like `Write-Host`,

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $test = return "test"
test
PS C:\Users\Neko> $test
PS C:\Users\Neko> $test = Write-Host "test"
test
PS C:\Users\Neko> $test
PS C:\Users\Neko>
```

but I can't fathom why having `return` in a grouping expression is causing such an issue.

---

Why is using `return` in groups causing a strange error and how can I remedy that?

This doesn't occur in subexpressions,

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $(return "test")
test
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217505/discussion-on-question-by-neko-musume-why-are-return-and-return-different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Neko Musume -- as per your request.

Because as per the MS Docs on the topic ...

> [About_Return | MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7)

... it can only be used as defined. Meaning 'Exit the current scope, which can be a function, script, or script block.', thus using parens, as you are trying to do, does not meet that criteria.

Answer (score 2):

**[`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) is a *statement*, whereas only *commands* and *expressions* are allowed inside `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).**

- **All *keyword*-based constructs are *statements***; to name a few: other *flow-control* statements (`exit`, `throw`, ...) and *loops and conditionals* (`if`, `while`, `switch`, ...) - see [about_Language_Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords) for the list of all keywords in PowerShell.

**In order to group (embed in another statement) a *statement*** (potentially even *multiple* ones, separated with `;`, as usual) - **you need `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**.

- Note that the operator's name is somewhat unfortunate; "sub-statement operator" would have been more descriptive.
- The primary use of `$(...)` is inside [*expandable strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), and it is typically *not* needed elsewhere; instead, `(...)` should be used when possible, so as to avoid potential side effects (and prevent visual clutter) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).

That said, in this specific case, as the [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return)  help topic states, **`return`'s purpose is to exit *the enclosing scope* (function, script, or script block), so using it as the RHS of a *variable assignment* never makes sense.**

---

**The reason for the can't-use-a-statement-as-an-expression restriction is rooted in the *fundamentals of PowerShell's grammar***, as summarized by a member of the PowerShell team in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967#issuecomment-561843650) (emphasis added):

> **PowerShell has pipelines contained by statements, not statements contained by pipelines**. That's always been the case, and **the way to put a statement within a pipeline is to use the `$(...)` syntax** — that's its only purpose to exist outside of strings in the language.

The **two most important consequences** to end users are:

- **You cannot use a statement *in a pipeline***:

  - That is, something like `foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } | % { $_ + 1 }` does *not* work.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - While you *could* use `$(...)` as a workaround(`$(foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i }) | % { $_ + 1 }`, doing so forgoes the streaming benefits of the pipeline; that is, the output from the `foreach` loop is *collected in memory first, in full* before the results are sent through the pipeline.
  - In order to get the usual *streaming* behavior (one-by-one passing of output through the pipeline), enclose the loop in a script block (`{ ... }`) and invoke it with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)<sup>[2]</sup>:

    - `& { foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } } | % { $_ + 1 }`
  - (Using *expressions* in a pipeline works, just fine, however: `1..3 | % { $_ + 1 }`)
- **You cannot use the flow-control statements `return`, `exit`, and `throw` with  `&&` and `||`**, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators):

  - That is, something like `ls nosuchfile || exit 1` does *not* work.
  - Instead, you must use `$(...)`: `ls nosuchfile || $(exit 1)`

---

Unfortunately, **these restrictions cannot be lifted if backward compatibility must be maintained**; quoting again from the previously linked GitHub issue:

> [Lifting these restrictions amounts to] a huge change in PowerShell's grammar (effectively creating a fork in the language)

- While PowerShell to date (as of v7.0) has had an ironclad commitment to backward compatibility which prevented serious breaking changes, a debate about whether to permit such changed and how to (carefully) manage them has now begun: see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13129).
- If such changes are eventually permitted, many longstanding annoyances could finally be tackled - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6745).

---

<sup>[1] Note that `foreach` is also a built-in *alias* for the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, but the command shown uses the `foreach` *loop statement* - see [about_ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach).</sup>

<sup>[2] If the statement has side effects that you want the caller to see, use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) instead of `&`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer *complements* my (already lengthy) [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62817188/45375) in order to address some of your analysis in the question:

> I understand that `return` prints to the console and does not have "output" per say like `Write-Host`

**It is *`Write-Host`* that has no output in the *data* sense**: that is, it does *not* write to the success output stream (stream number `1` - see [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection))

Instead, it writes *to the host* (the display; in PSv5+, it does so via stream `6`, the information stream), *bypassing* the success output stream, preventing capturing or redirection of the output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/453750) for background information, including when use of `Write-Host` (rather than `Write-Output` / implicit output) is appropriate.

By contrast, **`return` *does* send the output from its (optional) operand<sup>[1]</sup> to the success output stream**.

As for the surprising behavior of:

> `PS> $test = return "test"`
> `test`

**You've hit an *edge case*** (discussed in [this since-closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13146)): something that is *syntactically allowed*, but *doesn't make sense to do*: **the `return` statement *effectively short-circuits the assignment***: that is, `"test"` is sent directly to the success output stream (`1`), and the assignment is *ignored*, because the flow-control statement **`return` exits the enclosing *scope* - not just the statement! - before the assignment occurs**.

You can verify that `return` indeed still targets the success output stream as follows:

```
PS> $testOuter = & { $test = return "test" }; "[$testOuter]"
[test]   # proof that $testOuter was able to capture the `return` value.
```

However, it's easy to avoid this problem: **any expression or command (pipeline) can directly be used as the RHS.**

```
# Do NOT use `return` in the RHS of an assignment.
PS> $test = "test"; "[$test]"
[test]
```

---

<sup>[1] While using `return` with an *expression* (such as `return $foo`) is probably most common, note that it supports an *entire pipeline* as its operand (e.g., `return Get-Date | % Year`).</sup>