# How can I use the output of a Powershell command as an argument to another Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, command, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, pipeline

I want to collapse these Powershell commands:

```ps
$colour = ""
$colour1 = "Red"
$colour2 = "Green"
if ($var -eq 0) {
    # failure
    $colour = $colour1
} Else {
    # success
    $colour = $colour2
}
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor $colour
```

into one line, using the output of the `if` expression above as the input argument to `Write-Host`, something like:

```ps
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}
```

Things I have tried and which failed:

```ps
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `&{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &`{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor (&`{if ($var -eq 0) {'Red'} else {'Green'}`)
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `{if ($var -eq 0) {return 'Red'} else {return 'Green'}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `&{if ($var -eq 0) {return 'Red'} else {return 'Green'}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `&{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}}
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `&{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor &`{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `{if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}}`
Write-Host ("Answer = " + $var) -ForegroundColor `if ($var -eq 0) {return "Red"} else {return "Green"}`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass output from entire *statements* (such as `if`) as command arguments, enclose them in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--).

A simplified example:

```sh
# Note the use of $(...) around the `if` statement.
PS> $var = 0; Write-Host $(if ($var -eq 0) { 'zero' } else { 'nonzero' })
zero
```

Note that if only an *expression*'s or *command*'s output is needed, use of `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) is sufficient (and side-effect-free).

E.g., the PowerShell (Core) 7+ alternative to an `if` *statement* is the ternary *operator*, whose use is an *expression*:

```sh
# PowerShell (Core) 7+ only.
# Since an expression is used, (...) is sufficient.
PS> $var = 0; Write-Host ($var -eq 0 ? 'zero' : 'nonzero')
zero
```

For *commands* (pipelines), `(...)` is sufficient too.

```sh
# Since a command is used, (...) is sufficient.
Write-Output (Get-Item *.txt | Where-Object Length -ge 1kb)
```

---

For more information on `$(...)` vs. `(...)`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).