# How to escape the following regex, so its usable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, escaping, parameter-passing, quoting

As far as I know, there is no way in PowerShell to execute an exe with parameters specified in a variable and direct the return of the exe into a variable. Therefore I am currently writing a small function to make this possible. But now I am stuck at the point that the parameters have to be passed individually when calling with `&`. (This is not necessary for all programs, but some programs cause problems if you pass all parameters as a string in a variable) Therefore I want to use a split to write the parameters passed to my function into an array. And then pass the array with the parameters in my exe call.

For this I have the following regex:

```
[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'
```

This regex allows that single and double quotes are taken into account when passing parameters and that a text with spaces inside them is not split.

But unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how to best escape this regex so that it doesn't cause any problems in the PowerShell script.

Here then still my function to make it a little easier to understand:
The function executes the file passed in the `$Path` parameter with the parameters from the `$Arguments`. Before the execution i try to split the `$Arguments` with the regex. As return of the function, you get an object with the ExitCode and the output of the executed file. Here you can see my attempt, but the quotes cause problems with the following code.

```
function Invoke-Process ($Path,$Arguments){
    [PsObject[]] $ReturnValue = @()
    $Params=$Arguments -split([regex]::escape([^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'))
    $ExCode = 0
    try {
        $ProcOutput = & $Path $Params | out-string
    }catch{
        $ProcOutput = "Failed: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        $ExCode = 1
    }
    $ReturnValue += [PsObject]@{ ExitCode = $ExCode; Output = $ProcOutput}
    Return $ReturnValue
}
```

The function is called as follows:

```
$ExePath = "C:\arcconf\arcconf.exe"
$ExeParams = "getconfig 1"
$Output = Invoke-Process $ExePath $ExeParams
```

I hope you can understand my problem. I am also open to other ways of writing the function.

Greetings

Comment: You should be able to pass an array of arguments to your binary and you should be able to capture it's output in a variable as far as I'm aware of

Comment: What makes you think you can't invoke an executable with arguments stored in a variable and assign the output to a variable? `$target = 'stackoverflow.com';$result = ping $target` appears to work just fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing you need to escape - the pattern is perfectly valid.

All you need is a string literal type that won't treat the quotation marks as special. For this, I would suggest a verbatim here-string:

```
@'
This is a single-line string ' that " can have all sorts of verbatim quotation marks
'@
```

The qualifiers for a here-string is `@'` as the last token on the preceding line and `'@` as the first token on the following line (for an expandable here-string, use `@"` and `"@`).

Try running it with valid sample input:

```
$pattern = @'
[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'
'@
'getconfig 1 "some string" unescaped stuff 123' |Select-String $pattern -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Which, as expected, returns:

```
gesture
1
"some string"
unescaped
stuff
123
```

---

As an alternative to a here-string, the best alternative is a regular verbatim string literal. The only character you need to escape is `'`, and the escape sequence is simply two in a row `''`, so your source code becomes:

```
$pattern = '[^\s"'']+|"([^"]*)"|''([^'']*)'''
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129742/45375) answers your immediate question well.

Taking a step back:

> there is no way in PowerShell to execute an exe with parameters specified in a variable and direct the return of the exe into a variable

No: **PowerShell *does* support both of those things**:

- `$output = someExternalProgram ...` captures the *stdout* output from an external program in variable `$output`; use redirection `2>&1` to also capture *stderr* output; use `>$null` or `2>$null` to selectively discard stdout or stderr output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980675/45375) for details.
- `someExternalProgram $someVariable ...` passes the value of variable `$someVariable` as an argument to an external program; if `$someVariable` is an *array* (collection) of values, *each element* is passed as a separate argument. Instead of a variable reference, you may also use the output from a command or expression, via `(...)`; e.g., `someExternalProgram (1 + 2)` passes `3` as the argument - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375) for details.

  - Note: An array's elements getting passed as individual arguments only happens for *external programs* by default; to *PowerShell-native* commands, arrays are passed *as a whole, as a single argument* - unless you explicitly use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), in which case you must pass `@someVariable` rather than `$someVariable`. For external programs, `@someVariable` is effectively the same as `$someVariable`. While array-based splatting also works for PowerShell-native commands, for passing *positional* arguments only, the typical and more robust and complete approach is to use [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)-based splatting, where the target parameters are explicitly identified.
  - A general caveat that applies whether or not you use variables or literal values as arguments: Up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x, passing *empty-string* arguments or arguments *with embedded `"` chars.* to external programs is *broken* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

With the above in mind you can **rewrite your function as follows**, which obviates the need for - ultimately brittle - [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) parsing:

```sh
function Invoke-Process {
  # Split the arguments into the executable name / path and all
  # remaining arguments.
  $exe, $passThruArgs = $args
  try {
    # Call the executable with the pass-through arguments.
    # and capture its *stdout* output.
    $output = & $exe @passThruArgs
    $exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE      # Save the process' exit code.
  } catch {
    # Note: Only If $exe is empty or isn't a valid executable name or path
    #       does a trappable statement-terminating error occur.
    #       By contrast, if the executable can be called in principle, NO
    #       trappable error occurs if the process exit code is nonzero.
    $exitCode = 127         # Use a special exit code
    $output = $_.ToString() # Use the exception message
  }
  # Construct and output a custom object containing
  # the captured stdout output and the process' exit code.
  [pscustomobject] @{
    ExitCode = $exitCode
    Output = $output
  }
}
```

Sample calls:

```sh
Invoke-Process cmd /c 'echo hi!'

# Equivalent, using an array variable for the pass-through arguments.
$argsForCmd = '/c', 'echo hi!'
Invoke-Process cmd @argsForCmd
```

Note:

- Since `Invoke-Process` is a *PowerShell* command,
  splatting (`@argsForCmd`) is necessary here in order to pass the array
  elements as individual arguments, which inside the function are then reflected in the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) variable.
- The automatic `$args` variable is only available in *simple* functions, as opposed to [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) ones, which behave like *cmdlets* and therefore automatically support additional features, such as [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters); to make your function and advanced one, replace the line `$exe, $passThruArgs = $args` at the top of the function with the following:

```sh
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $exe,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [string[]] $passThruArgs
  )
```