# Send-Mailmessage powershell adds line breaks

Tags: powershell, mailslurp

Got a really strange problem.
In my PowerShell script I use the `Send-Mailmessage` function;

```
Send-MailMessage -To $($Row.SubjectID) -From 'test@test.nl' -Subject $($Row.SubjectType) -Body $($Row.MessageData) -SmtpServer 'localhost' -Port 2500
write-Output $($Row.MessageData)
```

My Output `$($Row.MessageData)` says;

```
Hi test2! Account created here is the activation link http://localhost/register/activate.php?token=e8987ecebbf54a2b096ae5fd4af34f50be0eab90a989c69da864221cd49cee92
```

When I look a mailslurper it displays this:

```
Hi test2! Account created here is the activation link http://loca=
lhost/register/activate.php?token=3De8987ecebbf54a2b096ae5fd4af34=
f50be0eab90a989c69da864221cd49cee92
```

Anybody knows why the message is changed?

Comment: It is mail slurper.  You must have the word wrap option set.

Comment: As an aside: `$(...)` is only ever needed in two cases: (a) to embed entire _statement(s)_, notably loops and conditionals, in another statement, and (b) to embed an expression, command, or statement(s) inside `"..."`, an expandable (interpolating) string. Referencing a variable as a whole or one of its properties (and even a method call) requires _no_ enclosure; otherwise, `(...)` is enough for single expressions or commands. While not likely, the unnecessary use of `$(...)` can have side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).

Comment: @jdweng if i use the mail function in PHP

mail($email, 'Activate Account', $message, $headers);
The output is as excpected:

Hi test2! Account created here is the activation link http://localhost/register/activate.php?token=2ca9a2067833373ca80cedda4ab2c221f72d0b390ddb9c2eeb046ca3b513ec89

Comment: Try option bodyashtml (or other) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your help!
Turned on bodyashtml and fiddled with 'encoding'.
Used the parameters below and it works!
-BodyAsHtml -Encoding 'bigendianunicode'